# HaxeFlixel tilemap collisions

Tags: collections, collision-detection, haxe, haxeflixel

I am developing a game in Haxe with the HaxeFlixel Framework.

I decided to split the map in chunks so i can load new areas of the map at runtime (without loading screen). For that i put every chunk in an instance of `FlxTilemap`.

Now I noticed that, when i try to move a `FlxTilemap` (by changing its `x` and `y` properties) the collision detection (`with FlxG.collide(hero, map)`) does not work right.

To test why the collision detection doesn't work, I simply added a `FlxTilemap` to the scene and collided it with my hero:

```
map = new FlxTilemap();
    var mapData = "";
    for (y in 0...8) {
        for (x in 0...8) {
            mapData += "0,";
        }
        mapData += "\n";
    }

    map.loadMap(mapData, AssetPaths.tuxemon_sprites__png, 16, 16);

    for (x in 0...8) {
        map.setTile(x, 6, SpriteSheet.TILES.FENCE.LOOSE_1_RIGHT);
    }

    for (y in 0...8) {
        map.setTile(6, y, SpriteSheet.TILES.FENCE.LOOSE_1_RIGHT);
    }

    map.setPosition(
        map.x - map.width / 2,
        map.y - map.height / 2
    );

    add(map);
```

Collision detection is handeled in the `update()` method of the state:

```
override public function update():Void
{
    super.update();

    FlxG.collide(hero, map);
}
```

Am I doing it the wrong way or did I simply miss something?

EDIT:

There seems to be a problem in the HaxeFlixel collision detection. 
The collision will only be detected when the `x` and `y` properties of the `FlxObject`s are positive.
I want to have negative `x`/`y` positions as well.

Does anyone know a fix or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the bounds of your world space. Specifically, [`FlxG.worldBounds`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxG.html#worldBounds).